# Firebase Function Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created a firebase function when i tried to call it from client side it says. Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. This is my back-end side error after authentication post request.It looks like problem with headers.

firebase function code

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import cors = require('cors');
const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });

export const verifyToken = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (request: functions.Request, response: functions.Response) => {
        corsHandler(request, response, async function () {
            const bearerHeader = request.headers.authorization;
            if (!bearerHeader) {
                response.sendStatus(403);
            }
            try {
                const bearerToken = bearerHeader?.split(' ')[1];
                const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(bearerToken || '');
                const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(decodedToken.uid)
                response.status(200).send(customToken);
            } catch (err) {
                response.sendStatus(404);
            }
        });
    },
);
```

client side

```
 async verifyToken(token: string): Promise<void> {
    console.log(token)
    const firebase = FirebaseApiHelper.getInstance()
    const responseData = await firebase.request(
        "verifyToken",
        {},
        {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer" +token,
        },
    )
    console.log(responseData)
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code.  We can't see what `corsHandler` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function code does not handle a missing Authorization header correctly.  In that case, it will first call `response.sendStatus(403)`, then right after that, try to set headers again with a call to either `response.status(200)` or `response.sendStatus(404)`.

If you want to end processing after sending the 403, you should return out of the function early and do nothing else:

```
            if (!bearerHeader) {
                response.sendStatus(403);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Can I return a function call?